# дописать словарь в JSON

Tags: python, json

Скрипт записывает переменные в словарь и перемещает в json файл, при перезагрузки скрипта он стирает значения в json файле и записывает новые, как сделать чтобы он дописывал дальше и был возможность выборочно удалять данные с этого файла?

```
import json


firstname=input()
lastname=input()

filename = 'db.json'
myfile = open(filename, mode='w', encoding='Latin-1')

list=[]
list.append(firstname)
list.append(lastname)


with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list, myfile) 
    myfile.close()


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    st = json.load(f)
    a=st[0]
    b=st[1]
    print('firstname', a)
    print('lastname', b)
```

Comment: Как самый тупой и рабочий вариант - записывать сам json в txt файл, а потом парсить. Но 100% есть варианты раз в 20 лучше и удобней

Comment: Тогда ждём ответ от знатоков, если откликнутся

Answer (score 0):

Json имеет тип словаря, если упрощённо говорить. Для начала изучите [структуры json файлов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), в таком виде записи как вы хотели сделать работать не будет.

А теперь к теме вопроса. Если хотите открывать и перезаписать json файл, то его нужно сначала открыть в режиме чтения ("r"), загрузить, дополнить и только потом перезаписать.

Из-за того, что json файл нужно полностью загружать и перезаписывать, такое решение не подходит с работой с большим числом данных (будет медленно работать или в худшем случае произойдет переполнение памяти) и в многопоточных программах (может испортиться json файл при одновременном открытии и перезаписи)

```
import json

firstname = input()
lastname = input()

filename = 'db.json'

try:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        jsn = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    jsn = {"some_list": []}

jsn["some_list"].append(firstname)
jsn["some_list"].append(lastname)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jsn, f)


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    st = json.load(f)
    a = st["some_list"][0]
    b = st["some_list"][1]
    print('firstname ' + a, 'lastname' + b, sep="\n")
```

Удалять аналогично как в списках и потом перезаписать

```
import json

delete_name = input()

filename = 'db.json'
try:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        jsn = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    jsn = {"some_list": []}

if delete_name in jsn["some_list"]:
    jsn["some_list"].remove(delete_name)
    print(delete_name,  "remove")
else:
    print("not found")

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jsn, f)
```

Так же если не нравятся конструкции *try-except*, можно использовать модуль os для проверки наличия файла

```
from os.path import exists


filename = 'db.json'
if exists(filename):
    ...
else:
    ...
```